# Probability - Cats and chances

Tags: probability

I have a question that got me confused.

Id the store has cats and there is 40% of the cats are male, 45% of the cats are brown. 30% of the male cats are brown. If I chose 8 brown cats randomly with a return, what is the chance of at most two of them are not male?

I thought to d the formula for random+no return (N^k). to do it for all of the choices -> all female + one female 7 male + 2 female 6 males.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First you need to know what the probability is that a brown cat is a male: $P(m|b)$, while we know $P(b|m)=\frac{3}{10}$. So we first use conditional probability :

$$P(m|b)= \frac{P(m \land b)}{P(b)} = \frac{P(b|m)P(m)}{0.45} = \frac{0.3 \cdot 0.4}{0.45} = \frac{0.12}{0.45} = \frac{12}{45} = \frac{4}{15}$$

So let's define $p=\frac{4}{15}$, the probability of "success" in a repeated experiment (picking a brown cat, 8 independent times, because we return the cat after each experiment) and we want $P(X \le 2)$, where $X$ counts the number of successes (male cats) and is thus $\text{binom}(8,p)$-distributed.

The standard formulae for binomial distributions tell us that your desired answer is thus (this indeed corresponds to you proposed case distinction):

$$\binom{8}{0}p^0(1-p)^8 + \binom{8}{1}p^1(1-p)^7 + \binom{8}{2}p^2(1-p)^6 = \ldots$$

(time for a table or a calculator).